# How to implement port security in SDN using pox controller and ovs?

Tags: dhcp, security, sdn, ovs

How can I defend against DHCP starvation attacks or MAC spoofing in an SDN environment?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can see here: https://github.com/cybercoder/SDNPsec
I did it 2 years ago.

My algorithm uses token based authentication mechanism, and there is TOFU (trust-on-first-use) challenges.
You can implement your algorithm or implement sticky-MAC or other known disciplines.